# What is this small black insect with an orange stripe?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image: small black insect with an orange stripe]
[image: small black insect with an orange stripe]

Sorry for the poor quality of the second image, but a slightly different perspective may be useful.

This was taken in South Africa, Western Cape during the day.
They're fairly small, maybe around 5mm in length.
They were huddled together on an ivy leaf. I found another group of about five also huddled close together on another plant.

Comment: Some kind of Hemiptera nymph.

Comment: I guess they were grouped together because they had just hatched, and the eggs are laid in clusters.

Comment: Yes that does seem pretty similar thanks.

Comment: I checked again, and there are only three now of the other five I saw, but they're still huddled together in roughly the same spot.