# Identify black insect on Granadilla plant in South Africa

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Planted a granadilla tree 3 weeks ago and these guys appeared on the new growth.

Never seen them before.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can use an app like iNaturalist to both make a formal observation for the scientific community, but also to identify organisms with pictures. You'll need to take clear photos, especially of identifying features in order to get accurate suggestions.

Comment: See the guidelines at https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info for species ID questions.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! In addition to following @doremi's advice, please click on the [species-identification](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info) tag for important information about such questions. In particular, please [edit] in size information. Note that [this insect has been asked about before on this site](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/88363/46609), but did not get an answer. Consequently, you should try other resources such as [iNaturalist](https://www.inaturalist.org/). If you find out, please follow the [answer] guide and post it here. Thanks!